# What to do with required, but empty, implementations?

Tags: android, google-maps, code-cleanup, implements

I have a google map class

```
class MapActivity : FragmentActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
```

However i only use a few of the required functions provided by the implementations. 
All the unused methods i just place at the bottom of the class, like this:

```
override fun onConnected(p0: Bundle?) {
    checkLocationPermission()
    val mLocationProvider = FusedLocationProviderClient(this)

    mLocationProvider.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        goToLocation(task.result.latitude, task.result.longitude)
    }

}

override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String?, status: Int, extras: Bundle?) {
    //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String?) {
    //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String?) {
    //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

override fun onConnectionSuspended(p0: Int) {
    //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

override fun onConnectionFailed(p0: ConnectionResult) {
    //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
}
```

Is there a better way to dismiss of these unwanted required functions?

Comment: You could create a parent class to implement those interfaces, so your parent class will have those empty methods but the child class will be clean.

Comment: @diegoveloper and then i just implement these classes instead?
I suppose that's a solution :)
Any one else?
I was hoping for a easy quick fix to tell the class to just use the super implementation if not otherwise specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do anything (except create another class as suggested...), this the typcal tradeoff of the **Interface Segregation Principle**.

Anyway if you need to listen for location change update use

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
```

that tell you to implement only

```
void onLocationChanged(Location var1);
```

I also suggest you to use `#region` and collapse code on your editor to clean visually your class.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You must implement all the methods of `Interface`.

But yes, in the case of code cleaning, you can have one extra `class` for implementing all methods of `interface`. And use that class with your original.

[Click here](https://www.quora.com/Do-we-must-implement-all-the-methods-in-an-interface-in-Java) for more info.